# Codeigntier: Default route isn't calling "en" route

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I'm working on CI project, where i'm calling "en" route before the default controller. But it doesn't seem to work i have to provide the argument.

It works as:

http://193.42.156.121/airport/en

but I'm trying to make it work even with:

http://193.42.156.121/airport

My routes configuration are working fine on local server but it's not working same on online linux based server. Here is routing config:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "auth";  
$route['404_override'] = '';

// example: '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^fr/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^en/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^pt/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^de/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^ru/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^tr/(.+)$'] = "$1";
 
// '/en' and '/fr' -> use default controller
$route['^fr$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^en$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^pt$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^de$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^ru$'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['^tr$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

or if there is any issue with my .htaccess file ? I can't figure it out here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|styles|scripts|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: Check the controller file names and classes Make sure the **first letter only** is upper case example: `Auth.php` and `class Auth extends CI_Controller`

Comment: just checked it, everything on its place. It browse all the site correctly once we give " **/en** " also this project is on CI 2.0

Comment: another thing i'm not using CI's default class and i have a different class named **MY_Controller** which i'm extending

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /mypage/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things get really creepy, after few hours spending on this issue by viewing source page i saw there was a line break from the head of the document. And it was showing some warnings too well by removing the empty line no 1 from **index.php** present at root directory i made it work.